# Crontabbed shell script not able to create/write to a file

Tags: shell-script, files, cron

I have written a simple shell script to backup the tables in my DB using the `mysqldump` command. The command simply dumps the DB into a `dbName.sql` file. However, if the `dbName.sql` file doesn't already exists and I crontab this shell script, it doesn't work. What could be the reason? Are crontab scripts not permitted to create and write to files?

Comment: What does your crontab entry look like? Have you checked logs for `CRON` entries? Have you checked MySQL logs?

Comment: The cronjob was scheduled through a control panel. The script is running for sure because the output is getting written to a file and there are no errors. Its just not able to create a new file and write to it......

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn't work”? What command fails? What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron jobs can be run as root or another specified user. If that user does not have the permission to write to the `.sql` file the job will fail.

If the file exist and it has write permission for the user running the job the file will be written.

if the file does not exist and the user does not have permission to create files in target directory, the job will fail.

I can typically say

```
sudo touch /var/log/foo.log
sudo chown my_username /var/log/foo.log
```

now I can say:

```
echo bar > /var/log/foo.log
```

but if the file does not exist it will fail, as I have no permission to create files in `/var/log/`.

So question becomes if the user running the job have the right to create files where ever the output from `mysqldump` is written.

---

Now if I set up a cron job to run a script with this:

```
date > /var/log/foo.log
```

every minute, I can add:

```
*  *    * * *   my-user-name  /path/to/script
```

to `/etc/crontab`. As I have no permission to create files in /var/log/ the cron daemon will send me an email when the job fails.

After 1 minute there are no file. I go to a terminal and type `mail`:

```
$ mail
>N  1 Cron Daemon        Sat Jan 31 05:15   19/731   Cron <user@host>    /path/to/script
? type
...

/path/to/script: line 3: /var/log/foo.log: Permission denied
```

OK. My bad. I create the file and chown it to me. Now all is OK.

---

Have a look at these as well:

- [Where are cron errors logged?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207/28489)
- [What are the runtime permissions of a cron job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81805/28489)