# Setting up custom bash script to run only as sudo

Tags: shell-script, permissions, path

I made a script (name of the file is `update`) to update and upgrade in one command. All it is is:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/apt-get update
sudo /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade
```

I used the full paths, as well putting this in its own directory, `/home/user_name/custom_scripts`. I also made sure to designate this directory as `root`, the permissions are listed as

`drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Aug 23 00:12 custom_scripts`

and the executable script is:

`-rwx------. 1 root root 73 Aug 23 00:12 update`

I edited my path to look like this `/home/user_name/custom_scripts:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` yet for some reason this won't execute if I type `sudo update`. The weirdest thing is if I just try `update`, I get a `permission denied` exception.

I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Comment: Consider installing `unattended-upgrades` and `apticron` instead.

Comment: I think that you have changed the $PATH variable for `user_name` but not for `sudo`.

Comment: @Katu You're actually correct, but I had to edit the dafualt path in `/etc/sudoers`. So that's what the problem was after all.

Comment: @Astrum because the comment helped, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have it just run using Cron.
Have a look at [What are the runtime permissions of a cron job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/what-are-the-runtime-permissions-of-a-cron-job) but essentially just copy the script to one of the cron folder such as /etc/cron.daily

I would also recommend removing the sudo as its redundant. Cron will run it as root.

Comment: Should I keep the file permissions the same? Or does it not matter since `/etc/cron.daily` is only open for root?

Comment: root needs execute permissions that's about it. you can leave them as they are though

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have changed the $PATH variable for `user_name` but not for `sudo`.

I'm surprised about the `permission denied`, if you have `sudo` at the beginning of the command, it should ask you for the password when you run it manually.

For what you are trying to do, I think an `alias` would be more suitable, check 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias